# nexus 5, can't see new texts for one person

Tags: sms, google-hangouts

Yesterday, I was texting this friend with whom I am romantically involved when all of a sudden, I couldn't see the texts between us anymore.

That is to say that I type the text and send it and she receives it but it never shows up on my screen, at all. On my side, it's like I never sent it. As stated, however, she receives it and can send some back, which I, again, don't receive even though it shows the text as delivered on her side.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend unistalling the app the install one more time if it do not help the simplest thing is installing another messeanger ( in google store there is a lot of it )

Answer (score 0):

I've just now solved a similar problem. I just texted someone on my HTC 626S (a couple of hours ago) a few times (and also received a few from him) but after ending the session I could no longer view the messages. I could view older ones but not the latest ones I just sent or received. Also, on ending the session I got a message saying that the message was stored as a draft, even though I'm sure I sent the last one. Apparently an older message of mine from a few weeks ago never got sent due to a loss of signal (the call was dropped) so Android stuck it in 'draft' instead. From that point on no newer messages could be viewed. What I did to fix it was to tap the draft message and backspace over all of the text. That deleted it and now all the messages I sent and received since then all show up.